# Modeling Product Variants

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, entity-attribute-value

I've been trying to model product variants and thought that I might need to use EAV. I might have been able to do it without EAV, but I'm concerned that I might have missed something. Here's my design:

[image]

Here's what I am trying to represent:

1. A `product` can have 0 or more `product variants` (e.g. a t-shirt product may have size and color variants).
2. A `product variant` can have 1 or more `product variant options` (e.g. the size variant can be small, medium, large).
3. An `SKU` is comprised of 1 or more `product variant options` (the `product_variant_option_combination` table would contain all the possible combinations of `product_variant_options. So, if there were 3 sizes and 3 colors, there would be 3 * 3 = 9 combinations -- and each combination would be given its own SKU and price).
4. A `product` can have 1 or more `SKUs`.

If the product doesn't have any variants, then just ignore `product_variants`, `product_variant_options`, and `product_variant_option_combinations`.

Is this design sound? Will I end up having problems querying this? Will it scale? Is it normalized?

**UPDATE 1**

@Edper:

> If a product can have 0 or many (optional mode) product variants (e.g. size, color etc). Does it follow that a product variants can also have 0 or many products having that variant?

I don't think so. It is possible that a product like a "t-shirt" may have a "size" variant and another product like "pants" may also have a "size" variant, but I think that's just only happenstance. There is no need to make "size" only appear as one record because "size" might have different context.

The products I'm dealing with vary greatly and they are bound to have similarly named variants.

**UPDATE 2:**

Here's an example of how I see my data:

[image]

I've boxed the variant `Size` and its associated values. I want to make it clear that these are not considered to be duplicate data. The `Size` variant for the 3 products is just happenstance. There is no need to normalize this, I think. Each product can have 0 or more variants -- and they are unknown to me. I expect "duplicates" (though they aren't really duplicates as they always are in the context of a particular product -- so, Widget 1's "Size" variant is not the same as Widget 2's "Size" variant).

**UPDATE 3:**

I see now that, in my design, it is possible for a `product` to have multiple identical `product_variants`. I think that can be resolved by making `product_variants`.`product_id` and `product_variants`.`name` a composite key. This means that Widget 1 can only have "Size" variant once.

`product_variant_options`.`product_variant_id` `product_variant_options`.`name` would also need to be a composite key.

**UPDATE 4:**

By updating my `product_variant_option_combinations` to include `product_variant_id` (FK to `product_variants`.`id`) and enforcing a UNIQUE constraint with `product_variant_option_combinations`.`sku_id` and `product_variant_option_combinations`.`product_variant_id`, I think I was able to prevent the problem of having an SKU that is both "Small" and "Large". Is this right?

[image]

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jul 30, 2014 at 03:35 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.17
-- PHP Version: 5.5.12

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `mydb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Widget 1');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `product_variants`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_variants` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_product_id_name` (`product_id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `product_variants`
--

INSERT INTO `product_variants` (`id`, `product_id`, `name`) VALUES
(2, 1, 'Color'),
(1, 1, 'Size');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `product_variant_options`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_variant_options` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_variant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_product_variant_id_name` (`product_variant_id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `product_variant_options`
--

INSERT INTO `product_variant_options` (`id`, `product_variant_id`, `name`) VALUES
(2, 1, 'Large'),
(1, 1, 'Small'),
(4, 2, 'Black'),
(3, 2, 'White');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `skus`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skus` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `skus_product_id_products_id_idx` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `skus`
--

INSERT INTO `skus` (`id`, `product_id`, `sku`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'W1SSCW', '10.00'),
(2, 1, 'W1SSCB', '10.00'),
(3, 1, 'W1SLCW', '12.00'),
(4, 1, 'W1SLCB', '15.00');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `skus_product_variant_options`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skus_product_variant_options` (
  `sku_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_variant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_variant_options_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sku_id`,`product_variant_options_id`,`product_variant_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_sku_id_product_variant_id` (`sku_id`,`product_variant_id`),
  KEY `spvo_product_variant_options_id_pro_idx` (`product_variant_options_id`),
  KEY `spvo_product_variant_id_product_var_idx` (`product_variant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `skus_product_variant_options`
--

INSERT INTO `skus_product_variant_options` (`sku_id`, `product_variant_id`, `product_variant_options_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 1),
(3, 1, 2),
(4, 1, 2),
(1, 2, 3),
(3, 2, 3),
(2, 2, 4),
(4, 2, 4);

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `product_variants`
--
ALTER TABLE `product_variants`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_variants_product_id_products_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Constraints for table `product_variant_options`
--
ALTER TABLE `product_variant_options`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_variant_options_product_variant_id_product_variants_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_variant_id`) REFERENCES `product_variants` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Constraints for table `skus`
--
ALTER TABLE `skus`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `skus_product_id_products_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Constraints for table `skus_product_variant_options`
--
ALTER TABLE `skus_product_variant_options`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `skus_product_variant_options_sku_id_skus_id` FOREIGN KEY (`sku_id`) REFERENCES `skus` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `spvo_product_variant_options_id_product_variant_options_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_variant_options_id`) REFERENCES `product_variant_options` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `spvo_product_variant_id_product_variants_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_variant_id`) REFERENCES `product_variants` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: If there are not that many similar variants from different products then your design is good. But again when a user choose a variant, would it come from pre-filled `ComboBox` for example or it comes from a reference table that is let's say bound to a `ComboBox`? If it is the latter then why is the reference table not shown in your design? But again your design is pretty good already.

Comment: Users will not be "choosing" a variant. Instead, they will be "specifying" a variant (and they can specify whatever they want).

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You could have a design like:

```
 +---------------+     +-------------------+
 | PRODUCTS      |-----< PRODUCT_VARIANTS  |
 +---------------+     +-------------------+
 | #product_id   |     | #product_id       |
 |  product_name |     | #variant_id       |
 +---------------+     |  sku_id           |
         |             +-------------------+
         |                       |
+--------^--------+     +--------^--------+
| PRODUCT_OPTIONS |-----< VARIANT_VALUES  |
+-----------------+     +-----------------+
| #product_id     |     | #product_id     |
| #option_id      |     | #variant_id     |
+--------v--------+     | #option_id      |
         |              |  value_id       |
+-----------------+     +--------v--------+
| OPTIONS         |              |
+-----------------+              |
| #option_id      |              |
|  option_name    |              |
+-----------------+              |
         |                       |
 +-------^-------+               |
 | OPTION_VALUES |---------------+
 +---------------+
 | #option_id    |
 | #value_id     |
 |  value_name   |
 +---------------+
```

With the Primary, Unique and Foreign Keys:

- PRODUCTS

  - PK: product_id
  - UK: product_name
- OPTIONS

  - PK: option_id
  - UK: option_name
- OPTION_VALUES

  - PK: option_id, value_id
  - UK: option_id, value_name
  - FK: option_id REFERENCES OPTIONS (option_id)
- PRODUCT_OPTIONS

  - PK: product_id, option_id
  - FK: product_id REFERENCES PRODUCTS (product_id)
  - FK: option_id REFERENCES OPTIONS (option_id)
- PRODUCT_VARIANTS

  - PK: product_id, variant_id
  - UK: sku_id
  - FK: product_id REFERENCES PRODUCTS (product_id)
- VARIANT_VALUES

  - PK: product_id, variant_id, option_id
  - FK: product_id, variant_id REFERENCES PRODUCT_VARIANTS (product_id, variant_id)
  - FK: product_id, option_id REFERENCES PRODUCT_OPTIONS (product_id, option_id)
  - FK: option_id, value_id REFERENCES OPTION_VALUES (option_id, value_Id)

You have:

- PRODUCTS e.g. Shirt, Jumper, Trousers
- OPTIONS e.g. Size, Colour, Length
- OPTION_VALUES e.g Size - Small, Medium, Large; Colour - Red, White, Blue
- PRODUCT_OPTIONS e.g. Shirt - Size, Colour; Trousers - Length, Colour

You then need to create a n-dimensional array, with the number of dimensions equalling the number of options for the product. Each element in the array corresponds to a product variant. There will always be at least one product variant for each product; as there is always the pseudo option of the product "as-is"

- PRODUCT_VARIANTS e.g Shirt 1, Shirt 2
- VARIANT_VALUES e.g Shirt 1: Small Red; Shirt 2: Small White

You may wish to have validation to ensure a SKU is not assigned unless values have been specified for all options associated with a product.

Based on the spreadsheet of how you see your data you could enter data in your tables as follows:

```
PRODUCTS
========
id  name
--- --------
1   Widget 1
2   Widget 2
3   Widget 3
 
PRODUCT_VARIANTS
================
id  product_id name
--- ---------- ------
1   1          Size   (Widget 1)
2   1          Color  (Widget 1)
3   2          Size   (Widget 2)
4   3          Class  (Widget 3)
5   3          Size   (Widget 3)
 
PRODUCT_VARIANT_OPTIONS
=======================
id  product_variant_id name
--- ------------------ -------------
1   1                  Small         (Widget 1; Size)
2   1                  Large         (Widget 1; Size)
3   2                  White         (Widget 1; Color)
4   2                  Black         (Widget 1; Color)
5   3                  Small         (Widget 2; Size)
6   3                  Medium        (Widget 2; Size)
7   4                  Amateur       (Widget 3; Class)
8   4                  Professional  (Widget 3; Class)
9   5                  Medium        (Widget 3; Size)
10  5                  Large         (Widget 3; Size)
 
SKUS
====
id  product_id sku    price
--- ---------- ------ -----
1   1          W1SSCW    10 (Widget 1)
2   1          W1SSCB    10 (Widget 1)
3   1          W1SLCW    12 (Widget 1)
4   1          W1SLCB    15 (Widget 1)
5   2          W2SS     100 (Widget 2)
6   2          W2SM     100 (Widget 2)
7   3          W3CASM    50 (Widget 3)
8   3          W3CASL    50 (Widget 3)
9   3          W3CPSM   150 (Widget 3)
10  3          W3CPSL   160 (Widget 3)
 
PRODUCT_VARIANT_OPTION_COMBINATIONS
===================================
product_variant_option_id sku_id
------------------------- ------
1                         1      (W1SSCW; Size; Small)
3                         1      (W1SSCW; Color; White)
1                         2      (W1SSCB; Size; Small)
4                         2      (W1SSCB; Color; Black)
2                         3      (W1SLCW; Size; Large)
3                         3      (W1SLCW;  Color; White)
2                         4      (W1SLCB; Size; Large)
4                         4      (W1SLCB; Color; Black)
5                         5      (W2SS; Size; Small)
6                         6      (W2SM; Size; Medium)
7                         7      (W3CASM; Class; Amateur)
9                         7      (W3CASM; Size; Medium)
7                         8      (W3CASL; Class; Amateur)
10                        8      (W3CASL; Size; Large)
8                         9      (W3CPSM; Class; Professional)
9                         9      (W3CPSM; Size; Medium)
8                         10     (W3CPSL; Class; Professional)
10                        10     (W3CPSL; Size; Large)
```

There seems to be nothing in your design from stopping the addition of the entry of the record (product_variant_option_id: 2; sku_id 1) so that SKU W1SSCW has now both the options of Small and Large. There is nothing to stop the entry of the record  (product_variant_option_id: 7; sku_id: 1) so that SKU W1SSCW also has the option Amateur.

Based on the spreadsheet of how you see your data you could enter data in my tables as follows:

```
PRODUCTS
========
product_id product_name
---------- ------------
1          Widget 1
2          Widget 2
3          Widget 3
 
OPTIONS
=======
option_id option_name
--------- -----------
1         Size SL
2         Color
3         Size SM
4         Class
5         Size ML
 
OPTION_VALUES
=============
option_id value_id value_name
--------- -------- ------------
1         1        Small        (Size SL)
1         2        Large        (Size SL)
2         1        White        (Color)
2         2        Black        (Color)
3         1        Small        (Size SM)
3         2        Medium       (Size SM)
4         1        Amateur      (Class)
4         2        Professional (Class)
5         1        Medium       (Size ML)
5         2        Large        (Size ML)
 
PRODUCT_OPTIONS
===============
product_id option_id
---------- ---------
1          1         (Widget 1; Size SL)
1          2         (Widget 1; Color)
2          3         (Widget 2; Size SM)
3          4         (Widget 3; Class)
3          5         (Widget 4; Size ML)
 
PRODUCT_VARIANTS
================
product_id variant_id sku_id
---------- ---------- ------
1          1          W1SSCW (Widget 1)
1          2          W1SSCB (Widget 1)
1          3          W1SLCW (Widget 1)
1          4          W1SLCB (Widget 1)
2          1          W2SS   (Widget 2)
2          2          W2SM   (Widget 2)
3          1          W3CASM (Widget 3)
3          2          W3CASL (Widget 3)
3          3          W3CPSM (Widget 3)
3          4          W3CPSL (Widget 3)
 
VARIANT_VALUES
==============
product_id variant_id option_id value_id
---------- ---------- --------- --------
1          1          1         1        (W1SSCW; Size SL; Small)
1          1          2         1        (W1SSCW; Color; White)
1          2          1         1        (W1SSCB; Size SL; Small)
1          2          2         2        (W1SSCB; Color; Black)
1          3          1         2        (W1SLCW; Size SL; Large)
1          3          2         1        (W1SLCW; Color; White)
1          4          1         2        (W1SLCB; Size SL; Large)
1          4          2         2        (W1SLCB; Color; Black)
2          1          3         1        (W2SS; Size SM; Small)
2          2          3         2        (W2SM; Size SM; Medium)
3          1          4         1        (W3CASM; Class; Amateur)
3          1          5         1        (W3CASM; Size ML; Medium)
3          2          4         1        (W3CASL; Class; Amateur)
3          2          5         2        (W3CASL; Size ML; Large)
3          3          4         2        (W3CPSM; Class; Professional)
3          3          5         1        (W3CPSM; Size ML; Medium)
3          4          4         2        (W3CPSL; Class; Professional)
3          4          5         2        (W3CPSL; Size ML; Large)
```

In my design you could not enter the additional VARIANT_VALUES record (product_id: 1; variant_id: 1; option_id: 1; value_id: 2) - so that SKU W1SSCW has now both the options of Small and Large - due to the primary key on VARIANT_VALUES and the existing VARIANT_VALUES record (product_id: 1; variant_id: 1; option_id: 1; value_id: 1). In my design you could not enter the VARIANT_VALUES record (product_id: 1; variant_id: 1; option_id: 4; value_id: 1) - so that SKU W1SSCW also has the option Amateur - due to the foreign key referencing PRODUCT_OPTIONS and the lack of a record in this table of (product_id: 1; option_id: 4) indicating that Class is a valid option for product Widget 1.

**EDIT**: Design with no PRODUCT_OPTIONS table

You could have a design like:

```
+---------------+     +---------------+
| PRODUCTS      |-----< PRODUCT_SKUS  |
+---------------+     +---------------+
| #product_id   |     | #product_id   |
|  product_name |     | #sku_id       |
+---------------+     |  sku          |
        |             |  price        |
        |             +---------------+
        |                     |
+-------^-------+      +------^------+
| OPTIONS       |------< SKU_VALUES  |
+---------------+      +-------------+
| #product_id   |      | #product_id |
| #option_id    |      | #sku_id     |
|  option_name  |      | #option_id  |
+---------------+      |  value_id   |
        |              +------v------+
+-------^-------+             |
| OPTION_VALUES |-------------+
+---------------+
| #product_id   |
| #option_id    |
| #value_id     |
|  value_name   |
+---------------+
```

With the Primary, Unique and Foreign Keys:

- PRODUCTS

  - PK: product_id
  - UK: product_name
- OPTIONS

  - PK: product_id, option_id
  - UK: product_id, option_name
- OPTION_VALUES

  - PK: product_id, option_id, value_id
  - UK: product_id, option_id, value_name
  - FK: product-id, option_id REFERENCES OPTIONS (product_id, option_id)
- PRODUCT_SKUS

  - PK: product_id, sku_id
  - UK: sku_id
  - FK: product_id REFERENCES PRODUCTS (product_id)
- SKU_VALUES

  - PK: product_id, sku_id, option_id
  - FK: product_id, sku_id REFERENCES PRODUCT_SKUS (product_id, sku_id)
  - FK: product_id, option_id REFERENCES OPTIONS (product_id, option_id)
  - FK: product_id, option_id, value_id REFERENCES OPTION_VALUES (product_id, option_id, value_id)

Based on the spreadsheet of how you see your data you could enter data in these tables as follows:

```
PRODUCTS
========
product_id product_name
---------- ------------
1          Widget 1
2          Widget 2
3          Widget 3
 
OPTIONS
=======
product_id option_id option_name
---------- --------- -----------
1          1         Size        (Widget 1)
1          2         Color       (Widget 1)
2          1         Size        (Widget 2)
3          1         Class       (Widget 3)
3          2         Size        (Widget 3)
 
OPTION_VALUES
=============
product_id option_id value_id value_name
---------- --------- -------- ------------
1          1         1        Small        (Widget1; Size)
1          1         2        Large        (Widget1; Size)
1          2         1        White        (Widget1; Color)
1          2         2        Black        (Widget1; Color)
2          1         1        Small        (Widget2; Size)
2          1         2        Medium       (Widget2; Size)
3          1         1        Amateur      (Widget3; Class)
3          1         2        Professional (Widget3; Class)
3          2         1        Medium       (Widget3; Size)
3          2         2        Large        (Widget3; Size)
 
PRODUCT_SKUS
============
product_id sku_id sku
---------- ------ ------
1          1      W1SSCW (Widget 1)
1          2      W1SSCB (Widget 1)
1          3      W1SLCW (Widget 1)
1          4      W1SLCB (Widget 1)
2          1      W2SS   (Widget 2)
2          2      W2SM   (Widget 2)
3          1      W3CASM (Widget 3)
3          2      W3CASL (Widget 3)
3          3      W3CPSM (Widget 3)
3          4      W3CPSL (Widget 3)
 
SKU_VALUES
==========
product_id sku_id option_id value_id
---------- ------ --------- --------
1          1      1         1        (W1SSCW; Size; Small)
1          1      2         1        (W1SSCW; Color; White)
1          2      1         1        (W1SSCB; Size; Small)
1          2      2         2        (W1SSCB; Color; Black)
1          3      1         2        (W1SLCW; Size; Large)
1          3      2         1        (W1SLCW; Color; White)
1          4      1         2        (W1SLCB; Size; Large)
1          4      2         2        (W1SLCB; Color; Black)
2          1      1         1        (W2SS; Size; Small)
2          2      1         2        (W2SM; Size; Medium)
3          1      1         1        (W3CASM; Class; Amateur)
3          1      2         1        (W3CASM; Size; Medium)
3          2      1         1        (W3CASL; Class; Amateur)
3          2      2         2        (W3CASL; Size; Large)
3          3      1         2        (W3CPSM; Class; Professional)
3          3      2         1        (W3CPSM; Size; Medium)
3          4      1         2        (W3CPSL; Class; Professional)
3          4      2         2        (W3CPSL; Size; Large)
```

Comment: I'm still trying to digest your solution. Does this approach address any particular problems with my design? If so, what? Does my design fail somehow?

Comment: As far as I see it a SKU is an attribute of a product variant. A product variant is a particular combination of product option values. You appear to have linked the SKU to a a singular product option value e.g Shirt Red, instead of a combination of values e.g Shirt Small Red. My design splits what the possible options are from which option combinations are actually available i.e. a Shirt Small Blue may not actually be available.

Comment: Can you please identify the PKs of the tables? For example, is `PRODUCT_VARIANT`.`variant_id` the table's PK? What about `OPTION_VALUES`.`value_id`? Is that the PK? I'm still trying to study your design to see if what you're saying about the SKU make sense to me.

Comment: "You appear to have linked the SKU to a a singular product option value e.g Shirt Red, instead of a combination of values e.g Shirt Small Red." <-- Did I? My `skus` table has a `product_id` FK. And `product_variant_option_combinations` is an itemized list of all `product_variant_options` for a given `skus`.

Comment: The PKs are the # attributes, so there are some compound primary keys such as for PRODUCT_VARIANTS the PK is product_id, variant_id. This means there is some additional validation in my design compared with yours e.g. in my design you can only enter VARIANT_VALUES for valid PRODUCT_OPTIONS, whereas in yours any PRODUCT_VARIANT_OPTION may be selected for any product. Also, you can only enter one OPTION_VALUE per PRODUCT_VARIANT i.e. only one size, whereas in your you could have a variant that is both Small and Large.

Comment: 1.) What table does `#variant_id` refer to? 2.) "whereas in yours any PRODUCT_VARIANT_OPTION may be selected for any product" <-- I don't see how this is possible since my `products` table is not directly connected to `product_variant_options`. 3.) "whereas in your you could have a variant that is both Small and Large." <-- isn't that what I want? If there is a "Size" variant, then I want to possibly have a "Small Size" and "Large Size"? I'm still a bit confused. Sorry.

Comment: I see now what you mean by, "whereas in your you could have a variant that is both Small and Large." My design definitely fails. I'm still studying your design. I do not want `OPTIONS`.`option_name` to be a unique key. It is perfectly OK for "Size" to appear multiple times (because "Size" for Widget 1 is not the same "Size" for Widget 2). If I remove the UK constraint, will there be problems?

Comment: In your design, where would the price go? Would it be in `PRODUCT_VARIANTS`? Also, how do I handle the "as in" case you mentioned? Not all products will have variants (as a matter of fact, probably majority will not have variants). I'm a bit lost with `variant_id` as it doesn't seem to relate to a table???

Comment: You could remove the UK on OPTIONS; however, you should ensure that users can still distinguish between the Size option that has values Small/Medium and the Size option that has values Medium/Large. Price should be a attribute of the PRODUCT_VARIANTS table in my design. variant_id is just a number to distinguish between the different variants of a particular product and does not relate to another table, you may wish to rename it to something like variant_number. For "as-is" product Widget 4 you could add a PRODUCT_VARIANT (product_id: 4; variant_id: 1; sku_id: W4) with no VARIANT_VALUES.

Comment: Still trying to understand your design. Thank you for your patience. Is the `PRODUCT_OPTIONS` table necessary? All it seems to do is relate the `PRODUCTS` and `OPTIONS` table. Couldn't the same be achieved by just defining an `OPTIONS`.`product_id` FK to `PRODUCTS`.`product_id`?

Comment: Isn't the only problem with my design is that `product_variant_option_combination` doesn't prevent a variant from being both Size = Small and Size = Large? Couldn't I somehow modify my table to prevent that?

Comment: Please see my UPDATE 4. I modified `product_variant_option_combination` and think I may have resolved the problem wherein an SKU can both be Small and Large. Thoughts?

Comment: The PRODUCT_OPTIONS table is a 'normalisation' if more than one product can have the same option; it is not necessary if this is not the case where you could use your suggestion is OK. Update 4 will stop a SKU having a Size of both Small and Large. However, you could incorrectly add a record in SKUS_PRODUCT_VARIANT_OPTIONS indicating that SKU W2SS (Widget 2) has a Color of Professional. Due to the compound primary keys in my design, in which different tables keys use the same attributes, this entry would not be possible.

Comment: I don't think the normalization of PRODUCT_OPTIONS is necessary in my case. Again, if Widget 1 has a "Size" option and Widget 2 also has a "Size" option, I consider those to be different. Widget 1 needs to be able to add, edit, and delete its options without affecting Widget 2. Widget 1's "Size" is not the same as Widget 2's "Size."

Comment: What happens to your design when PRODUCT_OPTIONS table is removed? (Particularly `FK: product_id, option_id REFERENCES PRODUCT_OPTIONS (product_id, option_id)`? Is there a solution that doesn't require `variant_id`?

Comment: I have added a design without the PRODUCT_OPTIONS table, and renamed variant_id to be sku_id.

Comment: Is `OPTIONS`.`option_id` not supposed to be an auto-incrementing value? My problem with `variant_id` (which you renamed with `sku_id` is that it's not a FK to something, which is why I was asking if there is a solution that doesn't need such a "magic number" -- but maybe it is indeed needed). Now, in the latest design, I see yet another strange column like `variant_id` (which is the addition of this `OPTIONS`.`option_id` column). Thoughts?

Comment: OPTIONS.option_id may be an auto-incrementing value but it does not need to be. The compound primary keys are required in order to enforce the required integrity constraints, primarily that records in each table are kept in product 'groups'.

Comment: That was an awesome topic and answer. I'd like to understand how could a sql query be able to find a product typed at search box like: "widget 1 small white" ?

Comment: @DrabJay If a user selects Widget 1 (Size - Small) and (Color - White), based on the second database model, how would I get the sku value?, I’m kind of lost there...

Comment: @DrabJay : it's not working for saving product variation . Like one product can multiple variatians . In that case how it will save the data

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie ; it's not working for saving product variation . Like one product can multiple variatians . In that case how it will save the data

Comment: so can you help me understand this design here,
as I can't seem to understand what is the idea of having every foreign key as a primary key here

Comment: @DrabJay In this design is there any way to prevent 2 identical variants? For example having a (t-shirt with size: small, color: blue). And then another variant with the same values (size:small and color:blue).

Comment: I have read this whole thing as I was watching a tense moment in a movie. I thought @DrabJay would explode at some point due to StackOverFlowNewbie firing all those questions at him :) In any case this is an example of the art of asking a question..

I am just wondering how this design (since it's an accepted answer) turned out for you? I am kind of having the same dilemma and I would love to hear your experience in building this. Would you be kind enough to share? Thanks..

Comment: I know its little offtopic, but what is considered as final product variation? and how to receive for example Large Black T-shirt which is combination of size, color and product?

Comment: Oh okey. SKU table provides this functionality. SKU object is 'final product' that can be ordered etc.