# Simple Product Variants Design

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to design a database that could store variation of products.  So if,
**user choose :**
[image: User Choice]
There will be 3 product variant(Small White, XL Black, XL White).

I've read the accepted answer from [Modeling Product Variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923469/modeling-product-variants) and got a question.
What the drawback of using this simple design?
[image: Simple Design]
so the table would look like :
[image: Inserted Value]

Comment: There is a potential normalization problem here, because you would be storing the size repeatedly for different skews (e.g. `XL White`, `XL Black`, the XL is repeated).

Comment: Thank you. I'll reread what normalization is then.

Comment: It has to do with storing/not storing the same data over and over again when you don't need to.  For such a simple size scheme as you showed us, it may not matter.  But later on this could become an issue.

Comment: Would there still potential issue If i add product_id as prefix to sku_value?

Comment: No...the issue here is that you're storing size and color in a single denormalized column.

Comment: Isn't the [accepted answer](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d3z3vN9hm8LE8GNEOMoXrymbt7BaNdor) will also store size and color in single column?

Comment: Oh i got it(maybe). The sku_value in the [accepted answer](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d3z3vN9hm8LE8GNEOMoXrymbt7BaNdor) act as reference, not holding the value itself.