# check related object or not

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I need to check my object related or not ORM postgresql/

I have two object ItemVariationValue and ItemVariation i need to check
**ItemVariationValue** has relation with **ItemVariation**

**models.py**

```
class ItemVariation(models.Model):
    item=models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
    item_code=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    keywords= models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='dishes/', blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class ItemVariationValue(models.Model):
    item=models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_variation=models.ForeignKey(ItemVariation,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute=models.ForeignKey(Attribute,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute_value=models.ForeignKey(AttributeValue,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**views.py**

```
def get_items(request):    # request= {"order_details": "varxxx:1"}
    order=request.data['order_details']
    items = order.split(',')
    total = 0
    for item in items:
        od = item.split(':')
        sku = str(od[0])
        qty = int(od[1])
        itemvariation=ItemVariation.objects.get(item_code=sku)



# if ItemVariationValue.item_variation has ForeignKey(ItemVariation):
```

Comment: Please first fix the attribute names: `ForeignKey`s should *not* have an `_id` suffix. Right now this will introduce attributes like `item_variation_id_id`.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note** (`ForeignKey` nomenclature): `ForeignKey`s should *not* have an `_id` suffix, since Django will automatically construct an extra field `fieldname_id` that contains the primary key. By writing an `_id` suffix, you will introduce extra attributes like `item_variation_id_id`. Although strictly speaking that is not a problem, it introduces a lot of confusion. For example `my_itemvariationvalue.itemvariation_id` will result in an `ItemVariation` object, etc.

If you fix the `ForeignKey` names, you can check this like:

```
# given the ForeignKey is named itemvariation, not itemvariation_id and use Comparison Operators 

if my_itemvariationvalue.itemvariation_id == my_itemvariation.id:
    # ... (objects are related)
else:
    # ... (otherwise)
```

By using the `itemvariation_id` here, we *avoid* loading the related object, and thus potentially an extra database query.

Comment: why are you using my_  is this suffix ?

Comment: @M4STER: the `my_itemvariationvalue` is the `ItemVariationObject`, furthermore that is a prefix :)

Comment: It is not clear can  you make it clear do i have do declare  my_itemvariationvalue ?

Comment: @M4STER: In your question you write "*I have two object ItemVariationValue and ItemVariation*", well if these objects are named `my_intemvariationvalue` and `my_itemvariation` then it does the trick. Somehow you need a reference to your objects.

Comment: i have added view. can make me clear with this example ?

Comment: But the above does not make much sense, since an `ItemVariation` can have zero, one, or *more* `ItemVariationValue`s. A `ForeignKey` is after all a many-to-one relation. Furthermore after sevaeral edits, you still fail to make the problem statement clear. What exactly do you *want* to do, not *how* do you want to do it?

Comment: I need to find single product and variable product and i have followed this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923469/modeling-product-variants

Comment: @M4STER: but the point is that it is *not* guaranteed that there is *one* `ItemVariationValue`, there can be *no* related `ItemVariationValue`, there can be *one*, and there can be mulitple. So it looks like you modeled it the wrong way. If a`ItemVariation` has (at most) one `ItemVariationValue`, you need to use a `OneToOneField`. Do you understand what kind of relation a `ForeignKey` aims to model? A many-to-one field, so that means that *many* `ItemVariationValue`s can map to the *same* `ItemVariation` object.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you have a ItemVariationValue object and you want to know if this object has ItemVariation. so you can easily do

```
#your code
itemvariation=ItemVariation.objects.get(item_code=sku)

check_relation_obj=itemvariation.item_variation
```

also if you think you may or may not have relation with ItemVariation
add blank=True,null=True with Foreign Key.