# Basic Database Modelling For Product

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I want to modelling database about e-commerce specifically product variant. I found one model, and I got a few variants of it, and I'm not sure which one to use right now. All model depends on this link: [Modeling Product Variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923469/modeling-product-variants)

I think the choice between the 2nd and 3rd models would make more sense but I can't decide. Which one is better for sustainability, maintenance and ease of use?

**First Model**
[image: First Database Model]

**Second Model**
[image: Second Database Model]

**Third Model**
[image: Third Database Model]

Thank you.

UPDATE1:

I continued research and I decided second database structure to go because of normalization is better than others.

Comment: The difference between options 2 and 3 is the attribute value table.   Do your products have enough distinct attribute values to make a separate attribute value table worthwhile?  Create realistic data for your tables and see which model works better.

Comment: I think,all models can work perfectly.This is a part of ecommerce database therefore attribute_value table's of values should be exactly different than other value.For example values will be Red,Large,20kg,17x18x13cm data which are define Colour, Size,Weight,Volume.In this case two different products may have similar attribute and values.If model2 is used, there will be no duplicate data, but if model3 is used, data will necessarily repeat. In this case whether the repetition of the data is a problem or should we proceed systematically?Another question is normalization better on the 2nd model?