# how to filter Grouped results to match more than one value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

-*The question itself might not describe the issue well, but I'm not sure how to present it*

I have implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24941744/9832888) design
,so I have the following table diagram.

```
 +---------------+     +-------------------+
 | PRODUCTS      |-----< PRODUCT_VARIANTS  |
 +---------------+     +-------------------+
 | #product_id   |     | #product_id       |
 |  product_name |     | #variant_id       |
 +---------------+     |  price            |
         |             +-------------------+
         |                       |
+--------^--------+     +--------^--------+
| PRODUCT_OPTIONS |-----< VARIANT_VALUES  |
+-----------------+     +-----------------+
| #product_id     |     | #product_id     |
| #option_id      |     | #variant_id     |
+--------v--------+     | #option_id      |
         |              |  option_value_id|
+-----------------+     +--------v--------+
| OPTIONS         |              |
+-----------------+              |
| #option_id      |              |
|  option_name    |              |
+-----------------+              |
         |                       |
 +-------^---------+             |
 | OPTION_VALUES   |-------------+
 +-----------------+
 | #option_id      |
 | #option_value_id|
 |  value_name     |
 +-----------------+
```

*fields with "#" are the Primary Keys*

I want to afford users to filter products using `option_values`. say I have the following product variant `shirtA(product) size(option) small(option_value), color(option) green(option_value)`, and a user would like to filter for all products that have are say `small and red` shirts, so the previous product variant should not be included.

I have tried doing this

```sql
SELECT p.product_id, p.title, p.description FROM product_variants pv
JOIN products p ON pv.product_id = p .product_id
JOIN variant_values vv ON vv.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
WHERE vv.option_value_id IN (6, 10)
GROUP BY (p.product_id, p.title, p.description);
```

but as you can see it includes the products that hold `option_value_id` **6** or **10** and not both, so how to remove products that don't have both option_values not just one?

---

**UPDATE 1**

to clarify what I need to do I want is : enforce all products selected to have all the option value ids the user sends (in a form of an array) `WHERE vv.option_value_id IN (6, 10)`. the idea is just like in most of e-commerce websites when user filters for his/her preferences `option_values`, so user might want to search for all products that are `large (let's say that is option_value_id "6") and red (option_value_id "10") and maybe green...` and so on. so I don't want any product that only has a "red" color but doesn't have "large" size to be returned, and if user added another say color to the filter say "green" color then all the returned products should match all three filters (having green and red colors and large size).

Comment: `...HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT option_value_id) = 2`

Comment: if you want to have both simple change 'in' to 'and' like WHERE vv.option_value_id = 6 and vv.option_value_id =10

Comment: Model the options as columns of the product.

Comment: `WHERE vv.option_value_id = 6 and vv.option_value_id =10`

this won't work, a single column's value cannot be both 6 and 10

Comment: Thanks @CountZukula I was wrong. I have added comment with out deep check.

Comment: HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT option_value_id) = 2
can you please clarify what does "2" mean, I am not sure I understand.

Comment: I cannot put options as columns in the product table as I would lose flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `having` clause.  Your question is unclear.  But if you want both, then use:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.title, p.description
FROM product_variants pv JOIN
     products p 
     ON pv.product_id = p .product_id JOIN
     variant_values vv
     ON vv.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
WHERE vv.option_value_id IN (6, 10)
GROUP BY p.product_id, p.title, p.description
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT option_value_id) = 2;
```

If you want just one, you can change the `2` to `1`.

Comment: Thanks.
I updated the question, can you please take a look to just to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

If dynamic SQL building is an option for you, you may use INTERSECT for filtering product variants:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.title, p.description 
FROM product_variants pv
  JOIN products p ON pv.product_id = p .product_id
  JOIN (SELECT variant_id
        FROM variant_values
        WHERE (option_value_id = 6)
        INTERSECT 
        SELECT variant_id
        FROM variant_values
        WHERE (option_value_id = 10)
    ) as vv ON vv.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id;
```

This might not be optimal query if you plan very large numbers of product variants and their options, but still the query is simple enough to try.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a predefined set of ids, perhaps you can make use of an array here.

```sql
SELECT p.product_id, p.title, p.description FROM product_variants pv
JOIN products p ON pv.product_id = p .product_id
JOIN variant_values vv ON vv.product_variant_id = pv.product_variant_id
WHERE vv.option_value_id IN (6, 10)
GROUP BY (p.product_id, p.title, p.description)
HAVING array_agg(distinct vv.option_value_id order by vv.option_value_id) = array[6,10];
```

Comment: `array(6,10)` is an invalid array literal. You have to use `array[6,10]`

Comment: it was complaining that it could not cast bigInt to Int so I added this ```HAVING array_agg(distinct vv.option_value_id) = ARRAY[6::bigint,10::bigint];``` but I am not sure what is going on here can you please clarify why did you use ```array_agg and distinct```

Comment: @OmarAbdelhady: you could also use `array[6,10]::bigint[]`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, updated that, wrote that line from memory so mistook the syntax :)

Comment: @OmarAbdelHady I slightly modified the answer still. I'll try to explain the array_agg+distinct. For each group, doing the `distinct option_value_id order by option_value_id` makes sure you get a nice list of id's, sorted, never repeating. This list needs to be aggregated into a single value, otherwise you can't use it as a filter. That's what array_agg does: it distills the list into a single `array`. That array can be compared by you, using `= array[6,10]`.

Comment: However, @gordon-linoff 's answer seems more succinct, more performant, and equally correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try his answer keeping yours in mind, I also updated the question as it might have not been clear.