# product variations table for ecommerce

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design

i am working on an ecommerce tables
and i came across variations where i didn't know how should it done
lets assume those are my mysql tables
[image: db]

my question is for example

I phone 14 pro max
have diffrent storages 128 and 256 and a diffrent prices ( not same as colors ) (in the end all of them are related to variations ? or when its diffrent prices it should be diffrent product_item) ?
doesn't that break the rule of not repeating thing ?
how do i handle that ?

btw the place i get this database design is from here:

Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HamqOuv2Cw

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: What is your 1 (clear specific) question? PS Put all & only what is needed to ask in your post, not just at at link. Don't expect us to watch a video let alone read another page. Paraphrase and/or quote with credit what is relevant & relate it to your post. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL. In code questions give a [mre]. This question is (clearly) a faq. Research is expected & duplicates of very duplicated questions are poor posts. Please use standard spelling & punctuation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modeling Product Variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923469/modeling-product-variants)

Answer (score 0):

Beware of "over-normalization".  It seems like the `name` and `value` of a "variation" could simply be columns in the table that needs them rather than having two more tables for them.

Write out the main `SELECTs` for the schema you have, then try to write out the equivalent `SELECTs` for my suggested simplification.

If you need to search on various attributes of a product, consider throwing all the attributes (variations) into a single column and create a `FULLTEXT` index on that column.  `MATCH...AGAINST...` is very efficient, when it is appropriate.

Comment: No because its one to many relation between the variation name and the values 
for example 
color can have 4 values red,blue,green